# Prevent auto clicked link XSS attack using CSP

Tags: javascript, xss, content-security-policy

Whilst using CSP for a slightly different purpose (sandboxing) I realized that a very simple auto clicked link seems to bypass even relatively strict CSP. What I am describing is the following:

Content security policy:

```
default-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-inline';
```

And the body:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">test</a>
<script>
  document.querySelector("a").click();
</script>
```

Obviously in a real attack you would include the cookie information into the `href` field first and probably wrap this in a hidden self-embedding iframe or make the domain redirect you back to where you came from (potentially with additional url parameters thus creating a sort of XMLHttpRequest bypassing `connect-src`), but this basic example does show the problem.

Is there any way to prevent this with CSP (which still does allow the execution of Javascript)?

---

### Similar attacks

The same thing can obviously be done with some other navigation methods as well. The reason why I was asking specifically about this method actually has more to with my secondary goals than XSS exploits. Either way, open to any and all real solutions.

### Irrelevant side explanation

Because of all the confusion how this could still be applicable even without `script-src: 'unsafe-inline'`. Imagine the following file named `api.ext`

```
print URLParameters.method
[...]
```

This file could then be called like `api.ext?method=<script src='api.ext?method=alert("test")//'></script><!--` (except you would need additional URL encoding and stuff, this is just to get the point across). Finding exploits like this is hard and they are quite rare, but things like `connect-src` seem to exist to prevent leakage of information even in those cases.

Comment: You might want to hover your mouse over the csp tag.. there's too many TLAs (three-letter acronyms), and you've chosing the wrong one...

Comment: How could this be done without `unsafe-inline`?

Comment: @levi If you have a XSS exploit where you control the full content from the first character (rare, but not unseen) you can simply self-embed in the outer embed and have your javascript in the inner embed. But either way, that was just a side note, the existence of `connect-src` shows that CSP also cares about Javascript evaluation XSS exploits.

Comment: @MarcB Ah, my bad, I was careless, got it correctly on my other post, not sure why I mistagged on this one.

Comment: @DavidMulder How are you gonna embed an iframe, or read cookies,  without executing JS code (inline & external can both be blocked via CSP)

Comment: @levi Ah, yeah, if you're talking about the fact that the 'strictest CSP' would allow no Javascript at all then you're indeed right. What I was actually thinking about was `script-src 'self'` in which case the attack described above is possible. (and the choice for the word embed was not the best one, I just mean `my.html?xss=<script src="my.html?xss=myjs"></script>`)

Comment: I believe inline code is blocked by default. So assuming `script-src 'self'`, how could one execute JS code, outside of modifying one of the sites external JS files?

Comment: @levi If you find an XSS exploit where you control the output from the first character (those can sometimes be found especially in API's) you can do the thing I described in the above comment... not sure what's not clear about it. And either way, that has nothing to do with this question, so if you wish to ask about it maybe opening a separate question might be wiser.

Comment: Okay... first, we assume the attacker has found an injection exploit and can inject arbitrary code into the target page. Now what does that code do: redirect the page, load an iframe, load a script? The latter two are controlled by CSP. So yes, you can pass information to an attacker controlled endpoint, so I see your point there — once code execution is obtained you can transmit information. But the original injection and bypassing unsafe-inline with api.ext (a reflected XSS) are both vulnerabilities. CSP is generally to prevent this script execution in the first place.

Comment: Why do you expect CSP to protect you from inline script attacks when you explicitly disable that protection using `unsafe-inline`? Adding `unsafe-inline` in the policy indicates that you trust the content of the page, and thus, you should make sure it doesn't contain any harmful JavaScript, including preventing XSS attacks otherwise.

Comment: @JacobBundgaard If you would have read the entire question or the comments you would have seen that 1) Even without `unsafe-inline` the attack can still be executed and 2) that CSP is concerned with such attacks as proven by the existence of `connect-src`.

Answer (score 2):

This is unlikely going to be a satisfying approach - and obviously it isn't based on CSP - but it might be your only option if you really have to prevent such attacks. Before using anything like this, make sure that there is really no way to disable inline scripts (which should cover most attacks). Moreover, you should send your feedback to the public-webappsec@w3.org mailing list with a [CSP2] subject.

Here my (incomplete) idea:

```
function guardMethods(clazz, methodNames, urlGetter, allowFilter, reportViolation) {
    var prototype = clazz.prototype;
    methodNames.forEach(function (methodName) {
        var originalMethod = prototype[methodName];
        if (originalMethod) {
            Object.defineProperty(prototype, methodName, {
                value: function () {
                    var url = urlGetter.apply(this, arguments) || '';
                    if (allowFilter(url)) {
                        return originalMethod.apply(this, arguments);
                    } else {
                        reportViolation(url);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    })      
}

function allowFilter(url) {
    // todo: implement
}

function reportViolation(url) {
    console.error('Redirection prevented:', url);
}

guardMethods(HTMLAnchorElement, ['click', 'dispatchEvent', 'fireEvent'], function () {return this.href}, allowFilter, reportViolation);
```

You would have to implement similar guards for location, location.href, window.open and other functions/properties/events which allow to redirect to other pages. If you miss just one, then you are still vulnerable. Forms, XHR and most other resources can be covered with CSP itself. As far as I know, the prototype hack does not work in some older browsers.

Once more, I do not recommend to use this. The chance that you make a mistake or that it does not work in some browsers or that a new API will be added which can be leveraged for redirects is just too high.

Comment: As I said in the post I was actually investigating this as I was trying to create a sandboxed environment and this seems to be quite an interesting alternative to Google Caja for my personal needs (I don't really need all the extra stuff Google Caja provides). Either way, with respects to the question I think this might be a viable approach if created as a standalone library with the sole intention to block these kind of things. Going to spend the rest of the evening trying to bypass this I think :D .

Comment: That didn't take as long as I thought it would. Dispatching a `MouseEvent` on the specific element still gets the click through. Maybe one could fix that by patching up `dispatchEvent`, hmm, lets see~

Comment: Didn' t have time to write a proper comment untill now, but patching up dispatchEvent is a lot harder than that: events bubble up and dispatching other events should be allowed. Additionally you need to switch `HTMLAnchorElement` to `HTMLElement`.

Answer (score 0):

CSP is one of the ways to reduce the damage done by XSS, but it is by no means a magic wand that fixes *all* issues caused by XSS vulnerabilities. This non-goal is also listed explicitly in the [CSP specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/CR-CSP2-20150219/#intro):

> Content Security Policy (CSP) is not intended as a first line of defense against content injection vulnerabilities. Instead, CSP is best used as defense-in-depth, to reduce the harm caused by content injection attacks. As a first line of defense against content injection, server operators should validate their input and encode their output.

If you have to run JavaScript code, but you cannot trust the code, then you could serve the page with a sandbox directive without the `allow-same-origin` flag. With this CSP directive, the page will run at a unique security origin, which does not share any state (i.e. cookies, DOM Storage, databases, ...) with the displayed origin. Consequently, injected scripts cannot leak information, because they cannot get the information in the first place.

For example, to allow inline scripts to run, but without access to same-origin data, use:

```
default-src 'none'; script-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox allow-scripts
```

Don't bother with blacklisting JavaScript methods as suggested by another answer, because 1) you will always overlook a method and 2) disabling JavaScript APIs may break your web application in unexpected ways, and 3) the attacker only needs one hole to do damage, and your (custom) application probably contains at least one method which can be abused by an attacker.

Answer (score -2):

Content Security Policy is for the security of the page itself. Navigating to another page is not a bypass or something that concerns CSP. CSP is only concerned with your page and what it can do. It's also not about restricting the utility of the browser for the end user (like the ability to install plugins or open links).

---

```
default-src 'none';
```

This tightens the policy to allow no XHR / Fetch / WebSockets / CSS / Font / JavaScript / Plugin content from anywhere. These all have their respective properties but in their absence the default property is used. You have not attempted to do any of these in your javascript.

```
script-src 'unsafe-inline';
```

This relaxes the policy to allow any javascript that is embedded into the page to be used. This includes onclick/onhover and that whole family of **unsafe** attributes. To quote the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/):

> In either case, authors SHOULD NOT include either 'unsafe-inline' or data: as valid sources in their policies. Both enable XSS attacks by allowing code to be included directly in the document itself; they are best avoided completely.

Instead of this, if you feel the need to embed content in the document itself for whatever reason, there are hash and nonce values that can be placed in your policy string to whitelist your inline scripts.