# Retrieve/restore native javascript function after being overwritten

Tags: javascript

Let's say we run the following line of code

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'click', {value: null});
```

Is there any way whatsoever to retrieve/restore the original `click` function?

And yes, I am aware that it is possible to trigger a click event through `dispatchEvent`, however it is possible to patch that up in a similar way. What I am asking about whether it is possible to restore the click event or somehow trigger that click function after it has been overwritten like that. Do assume that that line of code was the very first line of code being run.

Comment: you can delete the new one, i think click() is on `HTMLElement.prototype.click`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A way to restore the original implementation is by getting a reference to the namespace of another frame, and re-use the implementation from that frame. This method does not work if the page is running in a [sandbox](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/iframe.html#iframe.attrs.sandbox) without the `allow-same-origin` flag though.

```js
// Create a new execution context and get the implementation of "click".
var frame = document.createElement('iframe');
frame.sandbox = 'allow-same-origin';
document.body.appendChild(frame);
var click = frame.contentWindow.HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.click;
frame.remove();

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'https://example.com';
document.body.appendChild(a);

// Use the implementation.
click.call(a);

a.remove();
```

Comment: The prototype seems to be inherited from `HTMLElement`, so calling the click handler should be impossible on other elements: http://jsfiddle.net/zqpt08fk/ . Regarding the second thing: That was exactly what I thought might be possible, but I didn't realize how to do it. (Will upvote and probably accept if the first part of the answer is fixed or cleared up (clearned up in the case it isn't inherited in other browsers or something))

Answer (score 0):

You can just save the old function and restore it later:

```
var oldHandler = HTMLAnchorElement.prototype.click;
Object.defineProperty(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype, 'click', {
    value: null,
    configurable: true,
});
// do stuff...
Object.defineProperty(HTMLAnchorElement.prototype, 'click', { 
    value: oldHandler 
});
```

Make sure to set `configurable: true`, otherwise you won't be able to overwrite/restore it.

Comment: "Do assume that that line of code was the very first line of code being run."

Comment: Then there's no way to do what you you're looking for.

Comment: What I am looking for is to make it impossible. If it is not possible then that's great and that's a valid answer. Answering a different question however is not a good idea ;-)

Comment: Fair enough.  I should have read it more carefully.  I suppose that restriction just seemed so...unlikely to happen in the real world that it didn't register with me.

Comment: And btw, for the first 5 minutes (during the time period you answered) there actually was an old version of the line in there (with `HTMLAnchorElement` instead of `HTMLElement`) with which it was possible using `HTMLElement.prototype.click.bind(document.querySelector("a"))()`

Comment: See this other question of mine and you will understand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752566/prevent-auto-clicked-link-xss-attack-using-csp

Comment: "Is there any way whatsoever" - It's not impossible, someone can read the source without executing it, and inject it back in after the element is modified. It is impossible to get a DOMs prior state with JS though.

Comment: Ah.  Interesting problem after all.  And yes, TechnicalChaos is correct.

Comment: @TechnicalChaos I fear I am not following what you mean?

Comment: If I personally was attempting to overwrite your immediate DOM manipulation, i'd load the HTML source with a script (possibly with a small AJAX call to the same page's URL) and use a regex to poinpoint the <a href=""> line I was interested in (based on a manual read-through of the code). Strip out the attributes of the found string, then use JS to append them back in to the anchor. Something like that anyway.

Comment: I just used Anchor tags as an example of a .clickable thing btw.

Comment: @TechnicalChaos I don't think I am trying to manipulate the DOM as much as making it impossible from Javascript to navigate to another page through a click event. But maybe I am just misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: Manipulating DOM == Altering an element on a webpage. You're altering a click event and don't want it changing back right? Im stating how it could be changed back: Write the original HTML back by loading the page source with AJAX and finding the original bit of it, then overwrite your changes with something like an element.innerHTML call.

Comment: Expecting an answer to a different question however is not a good idea ;-)