# Some third-party JS code blocks ALL console.log() after page loaded

Tags: javascript, console, console.log, devtools

Suddenly, `console.log()` stoped working (tested in several browsers) as from a `.js` file and directly from dev tools console at the specific website ([preview link](https://8ybkn1ver1r07ycp-1592000625.shopifypreview.com)):
[image]

And works at the rest websites:

[image]

What can  influece or block console.logs ?

Comment: you can redefine the prototype of any object and even attach setter/getter to property.. for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042611/override-console-log-for-production

Comment: So it there any way to reassign console.log back to its initial logic ? And how I can make this script have more priority than the script which redefined console.log ?

Comment: You could store `window.alert`  in a variable on the start of page, and restore it on end of page (or every 5 seconds)

Comment: as far as I know there's no way to restore the previous state unless you just reload the object from scratch but in the case of console, and any other object I knew in advance was going to be screwed, I would load a js as the very first thing (with no defer and put on top of the page) that will save the original prototype so that would be easier to restore on demand... but that's far from being a clear solution. Differently as it was suggested above.. if you save the reference of an object that will be changed, won't save you. You need a deep clone instead

Comment: to make the last statement more clear: you can easily discard the window.alert hint that was totally out of topic

Comment: anyway to keep it simple you could really do something like `const original = console.log;` at the very beginning and then in any moment after the function was screwed, just riassign it to `console.log = original;` or just `original('logthiswiththenewfunctionname')`

Comment: Thanks @Diego De Vita! This really works as a nice workaround! But I'm still trying to find the script which brokes `console.log` logic

Comment: the link you shared hosts a page that loads forever doing only god knows what. The console.log keeps working even after a while.. I waited max 30 seconds. You are not going to find the answer you are looking for here

Comment: @DiegoDeVita [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8580431/1048572) (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29884379/1048572) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13990187/1048572)) should work for overwritten `console` methods as well.

Comment: @Max "*I'm still trying to find the script which broke `console.log`*" - just break it first. `[console, Object.getPrototypeOf(console)].forEach(o => { const original = o.log; Object.defineProperty(o, 'log', {get() { return original; }, set() { throw new Error("Don't mess with the console, idiot!"); }}); });` or just `Object.freeze(console); Object.freeze(Object.getPrototypeOf(console));` might do it.